# Problema de herencia en CSS

Tags: html, css, herencia

Estoy jugando un poco con flexbox e hice este codigo ...

```css
div.aside_nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(238, 65, 49);
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 90%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 10px inset rgb(180, 80, 41);
  box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px rgb(238, 65, 49);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition-property: transform, left, border, box-shadow, background-color, color;
  color: #fff;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.aside_nav:active {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
  background-color: rgb(221, 131, 123);
  border: 10px inset rgb(230, 171, 148);
  box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px rgb(255, 168, 160);
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 10000px;
}

div.aside_nav a {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition-property: border;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: none;
}

div.aside_nav a:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgb(175, 67, 25);
}
```

```html
<div class="aside_nav">
  <a href="https:www.youtube.com">
                    Youtube
                </a>
  <a href="https:www.twitter.com">
                    Twitter
                </a>
  <a href="https:www.facebook.com">
                    Facebook
                </a>
</div>
```

Pues bien cuando se presiona el `nav` de la derecha, la idea es que el color del texto sea negro para el `aside_nav`, y por herencia también se debería de aplicar sobre las `<a>`, por que no lo hace?

Cualquier consejo me vale, gracias de antemano .

Comment: No, ya se que es la especificidad, esto no es un problema de especificidad, es decir, no es que la declaracion color : #fff tenga prioridad sobre color : rgb( 0, 0, 0, ) !important, precisamente por que estoy usando !important

Comment: No, porque la regla `div.aside_nav a` por especifidad tiene prioridad. Si el texto no estuviera dentro del `a` debería funcionar.

Comment: `div.aside_nav a:hover { color : rgb(0, 0, 0); }`

Comment: Yo logre hacer lo que queria, agregue lo siguiente ...                 div.aside_nav:active a
{
    color : #000;
}